# Wikipedia API for personal website

Tags: wikipedia-api

If I search any keyword on Google like "Sesame oil" it shows content from wiki at right side. Those details are informative for users.

I wanted to know, is there any API provided by WikiPedia which I can use as well? So that if any user search for any keyword, details from Wiki can be shown as well.

Comment: Well no .. But, you can crawl content using php easily.. Its generally the first paragraph of the page.

Comment: Is that legal to crawl content and show on personal website?

Comment: its available publicly.. So, i don't think there would be any issue. At most you can give credit .. like a small tag to show that this content was originally published  at wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wikipedia [Search API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsearch) to find articles that are the closest to the keyword. Then once you've got the title, there's a publicly available [summary endpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#!/Page_content/get_page_summary_title), which gives you title, short text extract, wikidata definition and an image for an article what you can present to the user.

As for your question about whether it's legal - yep, it totally is.